# How to calculate the covariance matrix in blocks?

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-guide, data-analysis

There is a Matlab build in function `"cov"` to calculate the covariance matrix of a given matrix `C`. If `C` is too big, for example `1000*60000` double, and there is not enough RAM in my computer, it is necessary to write a function to calculate the covariance matrix of a given matrix `C` in blocks or pieces. My question is how to calculate the covariance matrix in blocks/pieces? Suppose the size of the given matrix is `1000*60000` double, which my computer cannot handle by using `"cov"` function.

Comment: Are you sure 1000 x 60000 is the right size? Normally you should have more observations (first dimension) than variables (second dimension).

Comment: @A.Donda, yes, 1000*60000 is the right size. 6000 features and 1000 time points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you have 60,000 observation of 1,000 variables then you can just compute the covaraince matrix in chunks and then combine them as you go:

1. Partition your observations into chunks of size N. (N will have to be determined to fit within your RAM)
2. Compute the covariance for the N'th chunk
3. Combine the N'th chunk with the total covariance for the previous N-1 chunks

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622/combining-two-covariance-matrices) is a discussion on how you combine covariance matrices. Basically, you want to keep track of both the covariances and means of the chunks as you process them and then combine by exploiting their mean square minus square of the means representation listed in the first property of covariances listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties).

Comment: @dpmcmixxvi, I have 1000 time points and 60000 features. Can you give a sample code?

Comment: On [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance) there is psuedo-code for a version of what I describe above for the special case of chunks of size N=1. Probably won't be very efficient in matlab with all those loops but you should be able to look at the equations on the wiki link and extend for the general case.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed they also provide the formula for combining two covariances at the very bottom. That should be all you need.

Comment: The formula is just for two datasets. What if there are more data blocks, how to deal with this situation. And I do not think compute the covariance of two datasets  is the same as computing the covariance matrix of a given matrix..

Comment: Yes, the formula is for 2 data sets. That's why you use the formula with the steps I described above. First combine the covariance for the 1st chunk (C1) and 2nd chunk (C2) that will give you a new temporary covariance C12. Then you combine C12 with the covariance for the third chunk C3 which will give you C123. Then you combine that with C4, etc.

Comment: The final result will be equal to directly computing the covariance matrix of the original given matrix?are you sure?

Comment: It is the same. The matrix for which you are computing the covariances has observations and features. You have to partition the observations to create N datasets then apply the formula and algorithm described above.

Comment: Yes. Online covariance matrices are computed all the time like this. Try it and see. If you are not sure, then try it for a smaller problem for which you already know the answer to check.

Comment: What is the difference between "naive_covariance" and "two_pass_covariance" ? Which one is better?

Comment: Why we have to use the formulation in the bottom of this webpage. Why not just call cov(data1,data2) ? And for my block data, data1 and data2 are also matrices, not a vector. How it goes like this?

Comment: Read the documentation on [cov](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html). cov(data1,data2) does not do what you think it would do.

Comment: Which one should I follow between "naive_covariance" and "two_pass_covariance" ?

Comment: Even if I use your method, it still shows "out of memory", since I have 1000 timepoints and 60000 features. It seems there is no way to solve the problem.

Comment: Then that means that you don't enough memory to hold even 1 of your matrices. Checkout the MATLAB memory limits [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform). In that case, just compute the covariances separately using the scalar equations and don't try to do it using matrices. However, if you that, when you compute them you will still need to store them somewhere. Since you don't have enough memory to hold even one matrix you will have to write the results to a file as you compute them.

Comment: By the way, you should verify a solution before accepting it then taking it back. It will make people less likely to want to spend so much time helping you.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know accepting the question and taking it back means something to you. How to compute the covariance separately using the scalar equation? What does that mean?

Comment: If I have a very small matrix, does that mean I can just use "cov(m)" to get the covariance matrix of the given matrix m?